# Hide shipping method for multiple store views

Tags: shipping, store-view

I am trying to create a solution for different shipping options in the cart based on store view and would appreciate any advice.

In Magento, I have 1 website (abc.com) with 2 store views (general) and (VIP)
I have the following shipping methods set up:
In bracket, I have the admin shipping method used

Economy FREE 4-6 day delivery (Matrix shipping rates table)
Standard 1.99 2-3 day delivery (Matrix shipping rates table)
Premium 3.49 1 day delivery (Matrix shipping rates table)
FREE Premium Delivery activated when order over 99 (Free shipping method enabled)

Attached is a screenshot of my shopping cart

[image]

I need the above 4 methods to be enabled on the (general) store view, but I want to disable the Economy on the (vip) store view. In Magento configurations, it is only possible to disable at the website scope level. When you select a store view scope there is no ability to disable based on store view.

To hide the FREE 4-6 working day delivery I understand there may be an option to code a conditional IF statement in php code, but I have very basic skills on php. I think the code may need to be placed in one of the files in checkout/cart maybe the available.phtml or shipping.phtml, something to do with sp-methods. But the php code uses a get method so I cannot access the hard code to wrap an IF statement around the specific shipping method.

I would appreciate some help in getting the desired solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: you can make condition in available.phtml based on store view and shipping method code ($_rate->getCode() in loop)

Comment: Thanks for your replies Zhartaunik,
Please could you confirm if I will need to "change the code pool in app/etc/module/Mage_all.xml" based on what I've understood about saving files into a local core folder? Minesh,
I am not an advanced php coder, so please expand on specific code for achieving your approach. Thanks

Comment: Hi @zinggyz, welcome to Magento SE! StackExchange is a Q&A, not a forum. If you have comments on the answers, then please post this as a comment. You could also update your question by editing it and add the information to it.

Answer (score 0):

By default shipping methods availability can be managed only in case of websites.

It achieved in system configuration file.

> /app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/system.xml

Let's find section for some shipping method. E.g. for `flatrate`

```
            <flatrate translate="label">
                <label>Flat Rate</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <active translate="label">
                        <label>Enabled</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </active>
```

2nd row from the bottom set 1 (it would be better if you copy this file into local folder by the same path `/app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/etc/system.xml` and make your changes there)

```
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

And then you can make this shipping method available for specific storeviews.

[image]

**I didn't totally tested how it works. Only checked visibility in two different store views. Looks like visual side is ok. Most likely there should not be any issues.**

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, I even copied the entire shipping folder just in case. It doesn't want to overwrite the core Magento copy.